# Difference in tag count between `git ls-remote --tags` and the `git tag` command. Why?

Tags: git

I just noticed that `git ls-remote --tags` and `git pull && git ta` return different results:

`git ls-remote --tags | wc -l`: 75417

`git tag | wc -l`: 75264

Is there any explanation for this discrepancy? Assuming my local repo only contains a single remote (origin), and that the remote repo is not being updated with new tags, I'd expect both commands to return the very same tags, yet they don't. Why?

Comment: Try `diff -u <(git tag) <(git ls-remote --tags | cut -d/ -f3-)` to see which tags occur only in one or the other.

Comment: @Thomas: use `-f3-` and/or substring so as to not mangle tags of the form `some/thing`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be related with tags with a `^{}` on them. `git ls-remote origin | grep "\^" | wc -l` returns 153 -- that's exactly the difference in counts between 75417 and 75264.

Comment: Aha, I totally forgot about the `ls-remote` feature that shows resolved tags, too. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your case was one of "too much information" in `git ls-remote`

In your case, you *do* have the same tags, as you found out and [mentioned in a comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619953/difference-in-tag-count-between-git-ls-remote-tags-and-the-git-tag-command#comment112500352_63619953)  But `git ls-remote` is just doing the first step of what `git fetch` would do: calling up another Git repository and having it list out its branch and tag names, and their corresponding hash IDs.  That's why you used `--tags` here, to cut down the listing to just tag-names.

For `git fetch`'s purposes, when a remote lists out its *tag* names, it lists not only the internal Git hash ID of the tag itself,<sup>1</sup> but also the internal Git hash ID of the tagged object, which is most often some commit object.  This allows `git fetch` to know, later, whether it has obtained the commit object and should therefore create the corresponding tag (see the section below).  So for each of these kinds of tags—see footnote 1—you'll get two output lines.  The line with the `^{}` suffix represents the resolved tag: see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

---

<sup>1</sup>Git's tags come in two flavors, internally: *lightweight tag* and *annotated tag*.  A Git *reference*—any internal Git name that starts with `refs/`—contains the hash ID of a Git object.<sup>2</sup>  A *tag name* is a reference that start with `refs/tags/`.  An annotated tag is, by definition, a tag-name whose hash ID is that of a Git *annotated tag object*.  The Git objects themselves come in four types: *commit*, *tree*, *blob*, and *annotated tag*, so if a tag-name names anything other than an annotated tag, that tag is by definition a lightweight tag.

An annotated tag object itself contains another Git hash ID.  That hash ID must be that of some annotated tag, or commit, or tree, or blob.  So Git can *dereference* this ID to find the underlying object.  If that's another annotated tag, Git keeps on dereferencing, as needed, to find some non-tag object.  The chain is required to end eventually by reaching a non-tag object, and that non-tag object is the target of the tag.  This is what `tag-name^{}` finds.

<sup>2</sup>This ignores what Git calls *symbolic references*, which contain the name of another reference instead of a hash ID.  Also, Git's *pseudo-refs* like `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on don't start with `refs/`; Git is a little inconsistent as to whether pseudo-refs are refs, or something else.

---

#### Git repositories don't need to have the same tags

There's no requirement that the set of tags in two different Git repositories match.

The default action for `git fetch`—and `git clone` itself is effectively a wrapper around `git init` plus `git fetch`, while `git pull` was until recently *literally* a wrapper around `git fetch` and still is effectively as well—is to copy any tags that point to commits that are fetched during the `git fetch` operation.  So if the source repository has tags that point to commits that *aren't* fetched by default, e.g., are not on any branch, those tags will by default not be fetched.  That would produce the kind of result you showed.

(Note that if you create tags locally and do not push them to the other Git, that would have the opposite effect.)

To see things in more detail, save the fetched tags in a file, and dump the actual tags into a file, and compare the two files to find out which tags are different.  (Or, in bash, use [the suggestion from Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619953/difference-in-tag-count-between-git-ls-remote-tags-and-the-git-tag-command/63620019#comment112500211_63619953).)